# In Android: How to Call Function of Activity from a Service?

Tags: android, service, callback, android-activity, android-intent

I have an Activity (A) and a Service (S) which gets started by A like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("updateInterval", 10);
i.setClassName("com.blah", "com.blah.S");
startService(i);
```

A have a function like this one in A:

```
public void someInfoArrived(Info i){...}
```

Now I want to call A.someInfoArrived(i) from within S.
Intent.putExtra has no version where I could pass an Object reference etc ... 
Please help!

PS: The other way around (A polling S for new info) is NOT what I need. I found enough  info about how to do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option is to switch from `startService()` to `bindService()` and use the local binding pattern. Then, you need to have A call a method on S at some point to register a listener or callback method. Then, S will have something it can call on A when some info arrives. You can see a sample project for that [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/18-LocalService/Patchy/).

Alternatively, you could leave `startService()` in place and use a broadcast `Intent` to let S tell A about some info arriving. You can see a sample project demonstrating such a broadcast `Intent` [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! My hopes and believes in forums have been restored :)

Comment: Just implemented your second suggestion and it works like a charm. thanks again!