# Interaction of Activity, Service and Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, interaction

I want to start a service that uploads some data to a web page. The service sends notifications to the notification bar (updates a progress bar). So far so good. 
Now, I want to show a activity when the user clicks on the notification in the notification bar. This Activity shall contain a button and optionally a status of the upload, i.e. I have to access the service that uploads the data. Is there a correct way to handle this requirement?

The service is currently started from a activity. I guess the main problem here is, to "link" the activity that is started from the `pendingIntent` on in the Notification with the service, i.e. access the service information. Does someone have a good example for that use case/issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just bind the activity to the service. Hope [this](http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843874/in-android-how-to-call-function-of-activity-from-a-service) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111362/prevent-new-activity-instance-after-clicking-on-notification) helps you out